# Over 1 file input function in form no work

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, html-table

I am creating the 2 files input to insert the file into a separate HTML table. My form inside has 2 file inputs function, now just 1 file input function can work and can store in the HTML table, another file input function didn't work to store in the HTML table.

Below is my form coding:

```html
<form name="form_id" id="form_id" action="javascript:void(0);" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:800px; margin-top:20px;">  

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label class="fieldlabels">Documentation:</label> <br>
                                    <input type="file" name="vasplus_multiple_files" id="vasplus_multiple_files"  accept="application/pdf" multiple="multiple"/><br>  
    <!--input type="submit" value="Upload" /--><br>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:60%;" id="add_files">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Name</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Status</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Size</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Action</th>
                                    <tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>


                            </div> 
                            
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label class="fieldlabels">Photo:</label> <br>
                                    <input type="file" name="vasplus_multiple_files" id="vasplus_multiple_files" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"/><br><br>        

                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:60%;" id="add_files">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Photo Name</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Status</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Size</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Action</th>
                                    <tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>


                            </div> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br>
</form>
```

My javascript code and whole code in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9fztkn60/2/

Hope someone can guide me which part I am getting wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Old school form submission *(which you should almost never use)* relies on HTML `name` attributes. You are using the same `name`... but really use `FormData` with the `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @StackSlave Thanks for your comment. Do you have ideas to solve it based on my question?

Comment: @StackSlave Can you give me a sample? Thanks.